# Want to know how Image.resize operation work in details in PIL liarary

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

I have used Iamge.resize() in PIL liaray to zoom my picture and it did well. I want to know how it work in details because I want to do the same thing using Javascript. I look up in the source code but only find some definition. There is no specific algorithm.

In particular, I use something like `img.resize((weight, height), Image.ANTIALIAS)`, It seem to use Lanczos Resampling Algorithm?

Thanks for everyone!

Comment: The docs for `PIL.Image.resize` link to [a page on the filters used](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/handbook/concepts.html#filters). Is that not what you need?

Comment: Took me 5 minutes to find source code for [resize function](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/blob/master/src/PIL/Image.py#L1790)

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I think I got my answers!